# preg_match regular expression, one new line but not two new lines, whitespace, etc

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I have this file/string:

```
   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.:
>>> DATA
<<< 554 delivery error: dd Sorry your message to foo@yahoo.com cannot be delivered. This account has been disabled or discontinued [#102]. - mta1070.mail.ac4.yahoo.com
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--p94IAEl4012027.1317751814/foo.com


   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mail.messaging.microsoft.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [foo] blocked using Blocklist 2, mail from IP banned; To request removal from this list please forward this message to foo@foo.com.
550 5.1.1 <foo@foo.com>... User unknown
<<< 503 5.5.2 Need rcpt command

--p94I91SC011973.1317751741/foo.com
Content-Type: message/delivery-status
```

And I need to get the part after "transcript of session follows---", up to the blank new line (or double new_line I think).

I tried something like this

```
<?php preg_match("/----- Transcript of session follows -----\n(.*)\n\n/",$email, $transcript_matches);?>
```

but is incorrect, instead of `.*` I probably need `any char OR new line but NOT two new lines`. And right after it `two new lines`. How can I write that?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to use an hexeditor to see what input you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You need to use the `//s` modifier to specify that `.` can match newlines. See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for details on regex modifiers in php.
- Use `.*?` to specify a non-greedy match (it will match the shortest string it finds).

Putting it together:

```
<?php preg_match("/----- Transcript of session follows -----\n(.*?)\n\n/s",$email, $transcript_matches);?>
```

*Also note:* If you are trying to get "--p94IAEl4012027.1317751814/foo.com" as part of your results, then notice that it is three newlines lines you are looking for, not two. In other words: two blank lines == three newline characters.

Comment: The `/m` multiline flag is for `^` and `$`. The dot match behaviour is changed with the `/s` dotall flag.

Comment: @mario do you know how the rule should look like ?

Comment: @mario, fixed. Good catch. My usual programming line of choice is ruby, where 'm' is means the same thing as php's 's'.

Comment: @adrianTNT, it's just switching the 'm' to an 's' at the end of the regex. I fixed it my answer.

Comment: @BenLee holly cow, that works :) I will look more into the details now. Thank you. Can you also tell me about the /s at the very end? From what I know at the end I was supposed to have a "/" delimiter, why the "s" after it ?

Comment: You can optionally add any of the modifiers after the last "/" in a regex. You can combine them too. So, for example, `/whatever/si` would match newline characters and also be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem I could think of is that you are looking for `\n\n`. Linebreaks for network-transferred data is commonly CRLF however. So you should prepare for the presence of `\r` at the end:

```
 follows -----\s*\r?\n(.*)\r?\n\r?\n/s
```

You might also want to use `.*?` instead of `.*`, or maybe `.*+`

Comment: I tried many of these combinations, I cannot get it to work. The one at the end is a \n\n in my file. How do I properly write this? `/----- Transcript of session follows -----\n([^\n\n]*)\n\n/` (trying to match anything NOT "nn", then "nn");

Comment: You did not understand. There ain't gonna be an `\n\n`